# How to upload a .msg file using a Memory Stream or File Stream that connects SP to Outlook via a data service?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, outlook-add-in

I have created a test method of programmatically saving an email from Outlook to a List in Sharepoint On-Prem using a Data Service.

The service copies that email and writes to the List successfully saving the email and attachments as a .msg file (which is also the goal)

However, I am having trouble retaining the formatting of the .msg file and it gives the following error:

"We can't open the 'C:\Users\ADMIN.....byteArrayTest3727.msg.' Its possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.

FYI...this isn't a permissions issue we have checked that on the Sharepoint List level.

Is this the best way to handle saving a .msg file to SharePoint with a Memory or File Stream so it retains the format?

---

```
public class OATSService: IOATSService
{
    public string Base64StringTest(string mailItem)
    {
        //string testFilename = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\source\\OATS\\OATSWeb\\Bulkogi.msg";
        //string testSite = "https:/....../site/X374520/";
        //string testTitle = "TEST";

        //byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(testFilename);

        //var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

        //byte[] decodedByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        byte[] decodedByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(mailItem);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(decodedByteArray);

        return mailItem.Length.ToString();
    }

    public string StreamTest(string mailItem)
    {
        string testFilename = "byteArrayTest" + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + ".msg"; 
        string testSite = "https:/....../site/X374520/";
        string testTitle = "TEST";


        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException
           ("The caller cannot be mapped to a WindowsIdentity");
        }



      //above is the mailitem code




        using (identity)
        {
        // Get credentials for the site.
        Uri uri = new Uri(testSite);
        ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");

        // Get the SharePoint site.
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(uri);
        // Get credentials for the site.
        context.Credentials = credential;


        // Get the web.
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        // Get the 'TEST' list items.
        List oList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TEST");


        byte[] decodedByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(mailItem);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(decodedByteArray);

        using (ms)
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(testFilename);
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(testTitle);
            context.Load(list.RootFolder);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, ms, true);
        }

        string msg = mailItem;
        return msg;
    }
}

[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
public string PostTest()
{
    string testFilename = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\source\\repos\\XXXX\\XXXX\\XXXX.msg";
    string testSite = "https:/....../site/X374520/";
    string testTitle = "TEST";
    //string testTitle = "filestreamTest" + DateTime.Now.Hour + DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second;
    //string testType = "DBE";

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

    if (identity == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException
       ("The caller cannot be mapped to a WindowsIdentity");
    }

    //using (identity.Impersonate())
    using (identity)
    {
        // Get credentials for the site.
        Uri uri = new Uri(testSite);
        ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");

        // Get the SharePoint site.
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(uri);
        // Get credentials for the site.
        context.Credentials = credential;


        // Get the web.
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        // Get the 'TEST' list items.
        List oList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TEST");


        using (var fs = new FileStream(testFilename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var fi = new FileInfo(testFilename);
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(testTitle);
            context.Load(list.RootFolder);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
        }



        return identity.Name;
        //return "Success";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide how you're opening `mailItem`. [Easiest way to read text file which is locked by another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389155/easiest-way-to-read-text-file-which-is-locked-by-another-application) may be helpful.

Comment: @TrevorSeward, Thanks please see the update above.

Comment: It's possible an application obtains an exclusive lock on a file, but give the link I tried a shot using `FileStream`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624188/1760623 as an example to go from a FS to an MS.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Thanks will give this a shot and let you know if it works!

Comment: @TrevorSeward saving the file from fs to ms kinda works...But what we are stuck at is what solution to copy the email contents (saving as a .msg or something else) AND the attachments WITHOUT LOSING THE FORMATTING. Outlook to WCF Service is our end goal.